# AIX versus Unix commands

Tags: unix, command-line, aix

I need all the Unix commands which are specific to [AIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX) machines.

For e.g.: for Unix `top` is equivalent to `topas` in AIX.

I need the list of similar commands.
Where can I find it? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Some examples: genld, genkld, slibclean, procldd, startsrc, stopsrc, installp, bootinf, getconf, lsattr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IBM `publib` documentation for System p and AIX is stored [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp) - `publib` is a *vital* resource if you're using *any* IBM product.

Look under `AIX Documentation`, `Commands reference`, `Categorical`<sup>(1)</sup>. This will show you what the commands are meant to do from which you'll hopefully be able to work out the similar commands for other operating systems.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Though, of course, things have moved since this answer was originally given (in 2009). You're looking for any resource that shows the `man` pages for AIX. Alternatively, assuming you have access to an actual AIX box, you should be able to enter (for example) `man ls` for a specific command, or `man -k directory` for a keyword search of commands related to directories.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference for commands to perform tasks across various UNIX flavours is http://bhami.com/rosetta.html. If you know the command on a popular UNIX flavour like Linux, you can find the same thing on other less popular unices like HP-UX or AIX.

I've lost track of the number of times it's helped me.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to know that UNIX is a common name for all Unix operating system. AIX, RHEL, FEDORA, SUSE, HP and so on, these are flavors of UNIX. 
There are very little difference in command between these flavors. Logic is the same.